# How does a photon scattering event yield information about the relative position of two particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, scattering

If we scatter photons on to two massive non interacting particles whose position is unknown in a finite region 'd', how does the scattering an detecting of photons yield information about the **relative** position of the two particles? (For simplicity consider a 2D scattering event)

Comment: If they are delocalised then that is what the photon scattering experiment will tell you. Or do you mean that their position is unknown in the region"d" ?

Comment: Yes their position is unknown in the region 'd'.

Comment: I sugeest you write that instead.

Comment: That is what i meant by "delocalized in a finite region 'd'"

Comment: However that is not what is meant by "delocalised" in physics. It helps if you use terms in the generally accepted meaning.

Comment: Sure i changed it.

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities:

1) Scanning. Use a beam of light with a waist much smaller than "d". Scan the area with this beam. Resolution is a sizeable fraction of the beam waist. Using pulsed laser and measuring time of flight will help if the region "d" - sounds more like a distance to me - is 3D.

2) Interference. The light scattered from the particles will interfere. The interference pattern contains information about their relative position. You need to use light of a wavelength somewhat larger than the separation that you anticipate. You also need to know how the individual particles scatter light. If they are anisotropic that will complicate the analysis.

Comment: "The interference pattern contains information about their relative position". Could you please clarify this point since this the part i don't understand.

Comment: Do you know what an interference pattern is?

Comment: Yes i do. Does this mean that the path difference between the two interfering waves represents the relative position?